# Connecting a server in a private subnet from a server in the public subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, nat, subnet, amazon-vpc

I created 2 subnets in one AWS VPC. One of them has an internet gateway for routing. The other has a NAT gateway.

I launched 1 instance into the public subnet with a public IP address and the other into the private subnet with only a private IP address.

Now, to make any updates, to install any packages or to configure the server to make it as a database server, how do I access it from the instance in the public subnet(considering the instance in the public subnet to be the application server).

I am not able to SSH to it. I get the error as in this image:[ssh-error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7bg8.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To SSH from a bastion host to a private server, upload the key file to the bastion host and use the following command

$ssh -i /home/ubuntu/keyfile.pem ec2-user@11.0.154.1

Also, while doing this ensure that the file permission of the key file is 400. We can also use SSH port forwarding to establish this connection

Comment: I wouldn't advise uploading your private key to the bastion server. Instead you can SSH directly to the private server, using the bastion as a proxy. Check out the ssh "-W" option, or the "ProxyCommand" config option.

Answer (score 0):

Open the port to SSH/RDP to the instance on the Security group, I would lock it down to your IP address, you do not want access to the server open to the world. This works for the public subnet instances, for private instances you can set up a bastion thru the public subnet or a VPN server.

[Security Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html)

[VPN Options](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpn-connections.html)

Comment: I do have a bastion host in the public subnet. Please look at my question for the error that I get when trying to SSH to the private instance from the bastion host.

Comment: Is the security group open between the public and private subnet? Is there a route between the two? Is ssh running on the private instance?

Comment: I have included the security group of the public instance to the security group of the private instance and vice versa. There is also a route that has a target routed to the local instances in the VPC(specified as "local"). I did enable a rule to allow SSH to the private instance but without accessing the instance, I can not tell whether SSH is running in it or not.